# using arraylist to populate the existing data in sqlite into spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, android-sqlite

Hi guys i have trouble to bind the existing data from sqlite to spinner. Do i have to apply arraylist ? If so how do i do it? Please help me i'm still new and this is for my project.

this is how the data taken from database :

```
public Cursor alldata()
{

  ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from shop", null);
  return cursor;
}
```

this is the coding that supposedly to receive the data and show it on spinner but i have no idea to do it :

```
SpListofShop = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpListofShop);

    Cursor cursor = db.alldata();
    if(cursor.getCount()==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO DATA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {

        }

    }
```

i really hope any of you can help me i'm too desperate

Coding to call the public arraylist function

this is the coding  to call the public arraylist  in databasehelper.java :

```
Spinner SpListofShop = findViewById(R.id.SpListofShop);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, db.alldata());
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    SpListofShop.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you dont need any array or list and `while(cursor.moveToNext())` loop - just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead

Comment: and no - do NOT use any `ArrayAdapter`s for that

Comment: may i know why i cant use ArrayAdapter ? the existing data have a table named shop with only a column called shopname. So the data that i am about display on spinner  is the one in shopname. is it bc i only have one column ? or? @pskink

Comment: why? because you dont have to use any loops for popolate tne list/arrau used by `ArrayAdapter`,- with `SimpleCursorAdapter` you simply pass a `Cursor` in the constructor - thats ALL - also as a bonus you have valid `id` in  `OnItemSelectedListener#onItemSelected` method

Comment: ok now i see thank you for the info :) @pskink

Answer (score 0):

1.change `alldata` as follows:

```
public ArrayList<String> alldata()
{

    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from shop", null);
    for (int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){
        values.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("row_name")));
        //edit, change row_name with your row
    }
    cursor.close();
    return values;
}
```

2.change spinner code like this:

```
Spinner SpListofShop = findViewById(R.id.SpListofShop);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, alldata());
adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

SpListofShop.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i wanna ask whether the row_name is the first data or the column name? i get confused and also thank you so much for the steps and the coding :) @touhidul islam

Comment: @j-h13 i just answered above why you should NOT use `ArrayAdapter` when your data comes from a `Cursor` - why do you insist in using it?

Comment: @j-h13, `select *...` return all data from your table, but, you want to show a specific name on the spinner, say, value of `name` row. If so, replace `row_name` with `name`

Comment: @j-h13 has this answer solved your problem? if so, please accept it

Comment: @TouhidulIslam sorry sir its not working sorry for late reply

Comment: @j-h13, what part didn't work please mention clearly, so that i can help

Comment: so basically i put that public arraylist <string> on databasehelper.java, and called it on selecttheshop.java and the app crashed while i tried to run it @TouhidulIslam

Comment: @j-h13 could you please tell me why dont you use `SimpleCursorAdapter`? why dont you do that the "easy way"? how long do you want to "fight" with `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: @pskink i didnt know how to apply it. i do read about it yesterday and see the few examples but i didnt quite get it ,, maybe if you show me how....

Comment: @pskink so i have to put that two lines in databasehelper and called it from another java class then?

Comment: @j-h13 did you try to google for `spinner simplecursoradapter`? if so, wasnt the first link like that: [Spinner with SimpleCursorAdapter Android](http://techin-android.blogspot.com/2011/07/spinner-with-simplecursoradapter.html) ?